# I Get The Error In Facebook App - The specified URL is not owned by the application

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I am get the following error in my facebook app

```
API Error Code: 191
    API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
    Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

please help me my friend you can check this error here

http://movieluver.com/try1.php

Please Help Me!.

Comment: try removing www from the url http://www.movieluver.com

Comment: i remove the www but it still display the error

Comment: Have you added your website in your app settings below **Website with Facebook Login** ?

Comment: Yes I am Also Add the Url @AnveshSaxena

Comment: Please Check It @AnveshSaxena Here : http://movieluver.com/123%20%28Medium%29.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening as you have added a `www` in it, if you want to go with `www` version then access you site on http://www.movieluver.com/try1.php which is not having any errors or issues. 
But as you are accessing it through http://movieluver.com/try1.php which is not your **Site URL** you are getting error,

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

add `movieluver.com`in your app domains so that there would be no issue in accessing your site with or without `www`. The same is suggested when you hover on `?` in App Settings

> Enable auth on domain and subdomain(s) (e.g., "example.com" will enable *.example.com)

Comment: using this how i checked the current user is liked the my facebook page or not ? Please help me my friend

Comment: You would require `user_likes` permission then you can, after user logs into your application giving the required permission, query if he has liked your page or not by FQL like `SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() and page_id=PAGE_ID` which will return page id if user liked it else nothing.

Comment: @KalpeshRajai I would also like to suggest you that you open the dialog boxes upon user's action and not `onload` as sometimes browser suppress these automatic dialog boxes.

Comment: Hello Friend, How Can I Implement When User Click On Button And How i Check The User is like the page or not? I want to add this technique into website so please help me my friend!.